# Does not add a user to Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add users to my Firebase cloud

I connected my project to the console.firebase

While I fill in the email and password it is not adding to my firebase.

I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: Any) {

    signUp()
    
}
```

this is a button for register

and this is the func signup:

```
  func signUp (){
    
     let name = nameValue.text
     let password = passwordValue.text
     let email = emailValue.text
     
     if (!password!.isEmpty && !email!.isEmpty) {
         Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email ?? "", password: password ?? "") { (result, error) in
             if error == nil {
                 if let result = result {
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     else {
         showAlert()
     }
}
```

Can anybody help to figure out this problem?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're handling an error at all. Is it throwing an error? Have you tried printing it to see what it says? Do you get a result object?

Comment: the reason is that I don't receive anything from firebase, it is not printing while tapping the button

I got only this


2021-07-13 20:53:03.855109+0500 NewsAggregator[11483:474848] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed

Comment: You don't have any print statements in the code that you're showing. How do you know you aren't receiving anything?

Comment: Bro, i had this lines:

    print("\(result.user.uid) = this is print")
                        print("\(password) = passwords ")


I deleted them in above

Comment: Did you print the error statement? Do you know there's not an error?

Comment: I got only this 2021-07-13 20:53:03.855109+0500 NewsAggregator[11483:474848] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed –

Comment: That is not an error statement related to this and is not something you printed - it is automatically logged by the system. I'm asking whether you have tried to `print(error)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234825/discussion-between-bakhtovar-umarov-and-jnpdx).

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution to my problem:

```
 if (!name!.isEmpty && !password!.isEmpty && !email!.isEmpty) {
         Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email ?? "", password: password ?? "") { (authResult, error) in
            if let e = error {
                print(e.localizedDescription)
            } else {
              //  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "main", sender: self)
            }
         }
     }
```